# How do I use Color.rgb?

Tags: java, android

I was following a tutorial, and I was experimenting with some pieces of code, and found that my Application kept crashing when I input "aditya". I know I'm using `Color.rgb` wrong, but I don't know how.

```
chkCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String check = input.getText().toString();
            display.setText(check);
            f (check.equals("left")) {
                display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            } else if (check.equals("center")) {
                display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            } else if (check.equals("right")) {
                display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } **else if (check.equals("aditya")) {
                display.setText(Color.rgb(184, 134, 011));**
```

Comment: When it `crashes` what do you see for errors in the `LogCat`?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with LogCat, but I think it says 'FATAL EXCEPTION: MAIN', android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String Resource ID', and then a bunch more red lines similar to the above.

Comment: LogCat is your friend when it comes to solving problems, as it tells you everything, for any future posts relating to app crashes, copy the LogCat to your post, include all the red text in the log that arises on crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set the text to an integer of the parsed color as opposed to setting the color of the text. Try using this:

```
display.setTextColor(Color.rgb(184, 134, 011));
```

Comment: It happens to the best of us ^.^ Glad I could help, be sure to mark it as an accepted answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
display.setText(Color.rgb(184, 134, 011))
```

is trying to set the text on the display to `Color.rgb(184, 134, 011)`.

What you are trying to do is set the color of the text.  To accomplish this, write

```
display.setTextColor(Color.rgb(184, 134, 011))
```

before you set the text on the display.

Answer (score 1):

I think it crashes because Android sees an int as a Resource id, so it's not finding the resource and it crashes, try replacing

```
display.setText(Color.rgb(184, 134, 011));
```

to

```
display.setText(String.valueOf(Color.rgb(184, 134, 011)));
```

It should work